# how to match something with regExp between roundbrackets

Tags: regex, apache-flex

I have this:

```
var regExp:RegExp = new RegExp("((.*?)%)");
```

and want everything between the `(` and the `%)`
the string looks like this: `(-24%)`

I now get a return back "(-24" and have searched for a long time to find a solution but didn't find any.

Comment: Do you want to replace the text inside?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the parentheses

use:

```
var regExp:RegExp = new RegExp("\\((.*?)%\\)");
```

for example, given the string "(-24%)", this regex will capture "-24"

**edited** my bad. forgot when creating the regex that way it needs double escape. fixed

Comment: still get this back traceRegExp: (-32%,(-32%,(-32

I also tried different ways of executing the regExp
text.match(regExp);
regExp.exec(text);

no difference

Comment: The percent sign probably needs to be escaped too

Comment: Escaping characters doesn't mean it won't search for them. It just takes away their special meaning.  For instance if this RegExp engine supports grouping you would want to escape the parens.  If he's already returning a paren in his match than it's not an escaping issue.

Comment: new RegExp("\((.*?)\%\)"); still has the same (wrong) result i'm now trying the trim idea

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going to have to do something with lookahead, lookbehind if you need to find what's inside something with a regexp.

Alternatively you could just trim the results after you get them.

Comment: Not in this case. All you have to do is match the part that interests you in a capturing group and retrieve it that way. Which is good, because JavaScript regexes don't support lookbehinds.

Comment: Very cool.  I know lookahead/lookbehind isn't a common feature.  This is a neat little trick